# Can not import Blender animation into Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, fbx

I am relatively new to Blender and Unity. Please help me understand what do I do wrong.
I try to have a simple curve animation imported into Unity. Idea is that curve grows along his path and then turns back. Here is that animation in Blender:
https://www.screencast.com/t/t9FedC1Jh
I achieved that by making keyframes for **Bevel Factor** property of a curve.

BUT, I can not import this animation into Unity. I want to have that curve as an object in Unity that animates repeatedly.

When I import **.blender** file into unity I have some "Default Take" animation but it does nothing. 
When I export Blender project into **.fbx** - there is no animation there at all.
See here: https://www.screencast.com/t/0NMko6TGFoxy

Please point me into right direction - how can I import that object into Unity correctly?
Thank you in advance!